# What is the most efficient way in Python to compute mean values within a grid cell?

Tags: numpy, nested-loops

I have a 2d array of data points (X) with corresponding observations (z) and would like to compute a grid of the mean values of z for each cell.

Using nested for loops with Numpy is inefficient. Is there a faster way using a built-in function or list comprehension? I would like to avoid Numba/jit if possible.

```
import numpy

x = numpy.random.rand(1000000)
y = numpy.random.rand(1000000)
z = numpy.random.rand(1000000)

nx = 1000
ny = 1000
xl = numpy.linspace(0,1,nx+1)
yl = numpy.linspace(0,1,ny+1)
zm = numpy.full((nx,ny),numpy.nan)
for i in range(nx):
    for j in range(ny):
        zm[i,j] = numpy.mean(z, where = ((x>xl[i]) & (x<=xl[i+1]) & (y>yl[j]) & (y<=yl[j+1]))) #4.5 ms/loop = 75 minutes
```

Or, 2D variant:

```
import numpy

X = numpy.array([numpy.random.rand(1000000),numpy.random.rand(1000000)]).T
z = numpy.random.rand(1000000)

nx = 1000
ny = 1000
xl = numpy.linspace(0,1,nx+1)
yl = numpy.linspace(0,1,ny+1)
zm = numpy.full((nx,ny),numpy.nan)
for i in range(nx):
    print(i)
    for j in range(ny):
        zm[i,j] = numpy.mean(z, where = ((X[:,0]>xl[i]) & (X[:,0]<=xl[i+1]) & (X[:,1]>yl[j]) & (X[:,1]<=yl[j+1]))) #4.5 ms/loop = 75 minutes
```

Comment: Where is the 2d array in your code?

Comment: Is this really a Minimum Reproducible Example?

Comment: @mkrieger. The array of points is defined by <x,y,z> and I want to compute the mean value of z within each cell. The cells are defined in the x and y dimensions. I guess I could it into an 2d python array if it would help.

Comment: The only 2D array is `zm`, everything else is a 1D array.

Comment: I've revised the question to include a Python 2d array, not just coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) you could use:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': pd.cut(x, xl, labels=range(nx)),
                   'y': pd.cut(y, yl, labels=range(ny)),
                   'z': z})

out = (df.groupby(['x', 'y'])['z'].mean().unstack()
         .reindex(index=range(nx), columns=range(ny))
         .to_numpy()
      )
```

Running time:

```
3.95 s ± 1.83 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Thank you @mozway! This sufficiently answers my questions.. You saved me hours!

Comment: @Mike This solution is inconsistent with the 2D version from your edit.

Answer (score 0):

What you are building is actually a sort of histogram.
So you could use the provided numpy functions as follows:

```py
import warnings
import numpy as np

x, y, z = np.random.rand(3, 1000000)
nx = ny = 1000

zsum, _, _ = np.histogram2d(x,y, bins=(nx, ny), range=((0,1), (0,1)), weights=z)
zcount, _, _ = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=(nx, ny), range=((0,1), (0,1)))
with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore", category=RuntimeWarning)
    out = zsum/zcount

print(out)
```

Here, I suppress the runtime warning complaining about division by zero, which in our case is intended to get the NaN values. Furthermore, I ignore the x and y edges returned by the `histogram2d` function as second and third argument and assign it to the throw away name `_`.
I create one histogram with the weights to sum up the values and another one with counts to get the average by the ratio.

efficiency:

Note, that you should specify a bit what you mean by it, because you can optimize an algorithm with respect to execution time, but also with respect to memory consumption, energy consumption, etc. From the comment `4.5 ms/loop = 75 minutes` it becomes clear that you are talking about execution time.

On my laptop, the answer using `pandas` by @mozway takes: `1.1 s ± 147 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`.

This answer using `numpy.histogram2d` takes `508 ms ± 56.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`.